# Reactive kafka Keep getting Timeout exception while producing message

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api, reactor-kafka

Keep getting `log:reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms. Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.` when trying to produce message on kafka.

Already made sure that I have Jackson core, Jackson databind and Kafka clients dependencies in the producer project. Also How do I pass security protocol in reactor kafka SenderOptions

Answer (score 0):

`Topic topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.` You have to create the topic before you can use it - either with command line tools, or with an `AdminClient`.

You can set any `ProducerConfig` property in the map passed into the `create()`.

```java
    /**
     * Creates a sender options instance with the specified config overrides for the underlying
     * Kafka {@link Producer}.
     * @return new instance of sender options
     */
    @NonNull
    static <K, V> SenderOptions<K, V> create(@NonNull Map<String, Object> configProperties) {
        return new ImmutableSenderOptions<>(configProperties);
    }
```